# elasticsearch completion suggest on multifield

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I'm trying to get suggestions from a multifield. I can't find examples like this, so maybe it's not the best idea, but I'm interested in your opinion.

mapping:

```
POST /authors
    {
       "mappings": {
          "author": {
             "properties": {
                "name": {
                   "type": "multi_field",
                   "fields": {
                      "name": {
                         "type": "string",
                         "index": "analyzed"
                      },
                      "ac": {
                         "type": "completion",
                         "index_analyzer": "simple",
                         "search_analyzer": "simple",
                         "payloads": true
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

data:

```
POST /authors/author/1
    {
       "name": "Fyodor Dostoevsky"
    }
```

query:

```
POST /authors/_suggest

    {
       "authorsAutocomplete": {
          "text": "fyodor",
          "completion": {
             "field": "name.ac"
          }
       }
    }
```

Requirements are:

- get query works with text "fyodor" and also with "dostoevsky", this example works only with "fyodor"
- be enable to filter suggestions

any ideas how can I achieve these?

Comment: Remove index_analyzer and search_analyzer from the mapping . keep it only of type completion..

Comment: that didn't change anything in the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the suggesters don't work well in multi-fields, so you could want to put it outside.
Secondly, to make you query work with both the name and firstname, you have to choose the outputs/inputs in when indexing the data.

Example of working code for SENSE:

```
POST authors

PUT authors/_mapping/author
{
    "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string" },
        "suggest" : { "type" : "completion"}
    }
}

POST authors/author/1
{
    "name": "Fyodor Dostoevsky",
    "suggest": {
        "input": ["Dostoevsky", "Fyodor"],
        "output": "Fyodor Dostoevsky"
    }
}

POST authors/_suggest
{
    "authorsAutocomplete": {
        "text": "d",
        "completion": {
            "field": "suggest"
        }
    }
}

DELETE authors
```

Result:

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "authorsAutocomplete": [
        {
            "text": "d",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": "Fyodor Dostoevsky",
                    "score": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Filters are not available for suggestions. To implement some kind of filtering, you can look at this [blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-adding-context-suggestions/) about the use of context in suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there possible to apply different weightings for name and first name like you can with regular queries?

Comment: Hi @Harry. 

Explaining this in detail would be outside the scope of this question and would make this thead quite messy. You can have a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html) or ask a new question and ask me to answer it. 

Regards, 
Heschoon

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Heschoon! The article is helpful but I'm still unsure how to make it work for completion suggester specifically. Any chance you can answer my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28268418/2926423)?

Comment: Done @Harry. I hoped it helped you :)