# Elasticsearch completion suggester on multifield with different weighting

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I'm using the Completion Suggester in Elasticsearch to allow partial word matching queries. In my index (products_index), I'd like to be able to query both the **product_name** field and the **brand** field. Here are my mappings:

```
POST /product_index

mappings: {
  products: {
    properties: {
      brand: {
        type: "string",
        analyzer: "english"
      },
      product_name: {
        type: "string",
        analyzer: "english"
      },
      id: {
        type: "long"
      },
      lookup_count: {
        type: "long"
      },
      suggest: {
        type: "completion",
        analyzer: "simple",
        payloads: true,
        preserve_separators: true,
        preserve_position_increments: true,
        max_input_length: 50
      },
      upc: {
        type: "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my data:

```
POST /product_index/products/2
{
  id: 2,
  brand: "Coca-Cola",
  product_name: "Classic Coke",
  suggest: {
    input: [
      "Classic Coke",
      "Coca-Cola"
    ],
    output: "Classic Coke - Coca-Cola",
    payload: {
      id: 2,
      product_name: "Classic Coke",
      brand: "Coca-Cola",
      popularity: 10
    },
    weight: 0
  }
}
```

And here is my query:

```
POST /product_index/_search

"suggest": {
  "product_suggest": {
    "text": 'coca-co',
    "completion": {
      "field": 'suggest'
    }
  }
}
```

This works great except that I'd like to give the **product_name** field a higher weighting than the **brand** field. Is there any way I can achieve this? I have looked into this [article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html) on using **bool** queries but I'm quite new to Elasticsearch and unsure how I can apply that in the case of completion suggester.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As redox said, the completion suggester is really simple and doesn't support entries boosting.
My solution would be to make two suggester fields, one for brand and one for product name:

```
POST /product_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "products": {
      "properties": {
        "brand": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "product_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "lookup_count": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "product-suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "payloads": true,
          "preserve_separators": true,
          "preserve_position_increments": true,
          "max_input_length": 50
        },
        "brand-suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "payloads": true,
          "preserve_separators": true,
          "preserve_position_increments": true,
          "max_input_length": 50
        },
        "upc": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When indexing, fill both fields:

```
POST /product_index/products/2
{
  "id": 2,
  "brand": "Coca-Cola",
  "product_name": "Classic Coke",
  "brand-suggest": {
    "input": [
      "Coca-Cola"
    ],
    "output": "Classic Coke - Coca-Cola",
    "payload": {
      "id": 2,
      "product_name": "Classic Coke",
      "brand": "Coca-Cola",
      "popularity": 10
    }
  },
  "product-suggest": {
    "input": [
      "Classic Coke"
    ],
    "output": "Classic Coke - Coca-Cola",
    "payload": {
      "id": 2,
      "product_name": "Classic Coke",
      "brand": "Coca-Cola",
      "popularity": 10
    }
  }
}
```

When querying, make one suggest on both the brand and product suggesters:

```
POST /product_index/_search
{
    "suggest": {
      "product_suggestion": {
        "text": "coca-co",
        "completion": {
          "field": "product-suggest"
        }
      },
      "brand_suggestion": {
        "text": "coca-co",
        "completion": {
          "field": "brand-suggest"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

You can append the list of suggestions of brand-suggestion to the one of product suggestion, after having removed the duplicates, to have list of suggestions with only relevant suggestions, no duplicates and the product suggestions first.

Another solution would be to use a query with boosting on brand and product, instead of using suggesters. This implementation is however slower since it doesn't use suggesters.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my question! I followed your steps but I keep getting the error -"ElasticsearchException[Field [product-suggest] is not a completion suggest field". I did specify that product-suggest and brand-suggest fields are both of type "completion". Do you happen to know why this error occurs?

Comment: Strange @harry, it works on my SENSE and Elasticsearch instance.

Can you delete the index and try my queries? I just edited them to make them work in SENSE if you copy-paste them...

Comment: it worked for me this time. It seems like the only difference was that I included the "analyzer" : "simple" parameter. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks  @Heschoon, but it didn't work if the completion field was in nested index. So, I had to remove it from nested index

Answer (score 8):

The Completion Suggester is actually pretty limited in term of scoring: you cannot do that. The only thing you can do is boost some entries but not the attributes inside an entry (see the `weight` options http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing).

That's because the Completion Suggester doesn't do a "real search" -> it doesn't use the index. It's a simple "dictionary" designed to do "prefix" expansions faster than with an index + inverted lists.

You should give a try to Algolia -> the engine is designed to answer to prefix searches in realtime + having different "weights" per attribute. Here is a tutorial to implement auto-complete menu targeting several fields

Comment: Thanks @redox for the great answer! It's helpful to know how completion suggester works under the hood and I'll definitely look into Algolia.

Comment: but Algolia is a SaaS... in contrary of Elasticsearch that you can install on your own system...