# Multi word partial search

Tags: elasticsearch

i am very new to the Elastic search.
Like to know how to search partial multi word search.
\

for ex :
My document 
{
"title":"harry porter"
}
i need this document with search with following string
1.)har por 
same as sql query (select * from books where title like '%har%' or title like '%por%')

Comment: Be aware that Elasticsearch is nothing like others databases, not only because it's NoSql, but also because it is mainly a search engine. I suggest that you get familiar with Elasticsearch's core concepts ([this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/intro.html)) before starting to use it: Elasticsearch is designed for full text search which is similar but in many ways more powerful than what you are asking here

Comment: Its one of my search use case. any way i got a solution using 'ngram '

Answer (score 0):

Using a [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) will provide *most* of the feature you want. It will find words starting with an arbitrary string, like "har" or "por".

[Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28279605/7954580) for a full example on how to set up a completion suggester.

As described [in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#completion-suggester-mapping), you can achieve multi-word search (i.e. returning "harry horter" from a search for "por") by creating your analyzer with the option `preserve_position_increments` set to `false`

```
PUT books
{
    "mappings": {
        "book" : {
            "properties" : {
                "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "preserve_position_increments": false
                },
                "title" : {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the doc bit confusing , is possible to show me the search request.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this : [Edge NGram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

This helps in partial multi-word search (similar to autocomplete suggestions). Hope this helps!